# Keyboard hangs up on iPhone SE after installing an update

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, software-update, performance

This is the second time this happened. Does anyone know if there any fix for this?

I installed their latest security update and when the phone restarted it made me enter my password. But when I was in the middle of typing in my password, the keyboard hung up in the process. I could move it to the side by swiping right and left but it didn't allow me to type anything. Then it let me delete something only to hang up again.

I managed to make these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Eventually I managed to restart it again by holding down the home button and the sleep/wake button.

Comment: You will always have to enter password (or pin depending on your choices) after a restart.  The phone is encrypted at that point and you won't be able to use a thumb print until decrypted.   Are you using apples keyboard only or do you have any third party keyboards installed?

Comment: @Tyson the keyboard in the screenshot is clearly the iOS default. Also, iOS will not load third-party keyboards on the lock screen (even when using e.g. Reply on an iMessage notification) or password entry boxes anywhere in iOS.

Comment: @tubedogg I know that the pictured keyboard is clearly apples default. I also know apple default keyboard is all that should load there.  Re-read the wording of my comment.  I asked about other keyboards loaded because I have an unproven theory about an issue I had not long ago.

Comment: @Tyson Well as long as we're clear. I didn't get that from how you worded your original comment, but fine.

Comment: @Tyson: No, I don't have any third-party keyboard. It's all Apple.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?

Comment: @Angelplayer: IDK. Whatever the latest one is. Like I said I just installed the latest update.

Comment: @c00000fd But it's not a beta, right?

Comment: @Angelplayer: No, it's whatever is available for the general public. I don't install developer previews.

Comment: @c00000fd Ok, just making sure.